# Failover Cluster validation test failed

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2016, failovercluster

Greetings fellow admins,

I'm trying to set up a SQL server failover cluster with 2 Windows Server 2016 servers on a VMware vSphere host. 
When validating the Cluster I got the following error:

**List Network Metric Order**

```
An error occurred while executing the test.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

[Here's the error message capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbfC0.jpg)

This error is so vague that I could not find where to even start searching. I tried to alter the Metric manually to 1 (server network) and 2 (iSCSI network).
The error log is also not helpful. 
I can provide more info, if needed, but I wanted to keep this post short.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was not that simple to find. 
The underlying Windows 2016 server template had an error on the network card.
So every time I tried to reinstall it, the error was already build in.